# Is there a way to configure default window split positions when interacting with commands?

Tags: init-file, window-splitting

I always enjoyed horizontal splits when interacting with `C-h k` or a magit commit window, or anything like that.

Now I'm seeing vertical splits when I interact with those commands.

Is there a way to configure this behaviour so I only get horizontal splits?

Comment: See the variables `split-height-threshold` and `split-width-threshold`:  https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Choosing-Window-Options.html

Comment: yep, that's it. Thank you very much. You could write an answer so I could accept.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The variables `split-height-threshold` and `split-width-threshold` can be customized to control how the function `split-window-sensibly` behaves:
https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Choosing-Window-Options.html  The variable `split-window-preferred-function` has a default value of `split-window-sensibly`, the former of which is used by `window--try-to-split-window`, which is used by .... In a nutshell, a few of the key `display-buffer` family of functions use these settings.